# Decomposition of natural number

Tags: number-theory

I want to find 3 natural  numbers  a, b and c such that 
$\frac{4}{193}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$.
Also I want the see the decomposition  of 4/313 too. 
I need to see these decompositions for my research on E-S problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe AT LEAST a common denominator?

Comment: I trying to see some decomposition for my research.

Comment: $$\frac{4}{193} = \frac{1}{50} + \frac{1}{1930} + \frac{1}{4825}$$
$$\frac{4}{313} = \frac{1}{80} + \frac{1}{3756} + \frac{1}{75120}$$

You can use the following c++ code for any E-S problem  \\ 

#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
main() { 
long int a,b,c,n=313, Max_Iter = 100000; 
for (a=1; a<=Max_Iter; a++) 
  for (b=n; b<=Max_Iter; b=b+n) 
     for (c=n; c<=Max_Iter; c=c+n)  
       if (n*(b*c + a*b + a*c) ==  4*a*b*c ) 
          cout << "a= " << a << "\nb= " << b << "\nc= " << c << "\n"; 
}